# Only anchor links working in nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm working with a website template, and one of the changes I want to make is with the contact link.  With the default template, all the links in the nav bar are anchor links that go to different sections in the page.  I'm wanting to change the contact link so it's a mailto link, but I've found that for some reason external links don't work in the nav bar.

My problem is that the template consists of a whole bunch of CSS and JS documents, and I have no idea what part of the code would be causing this problem.  External links work elsewhere in the page, but just not in the nav bar.  Do you guys have any idea what kind of code might cause this so that I can have a better idea of where to look to solve the problem?

For what it's worth, the code looks like this:

```
    <section id="intro">
        <nav id="nav" style="background:-webkit-canvas(background) repeat;">
            <nav id="nav-1" style="background:-moz-element(#background) repeat;">
            <!-- The content between <span> </span> tags will be hidden on mobile version -->
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="#education">Edu<span>cation</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Por<span>tfolio</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#experience">Exp<span>erience</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Con<span>tact</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

Comment: Having the relevant CSS would be critical to assisting you.

Comment: When you say "don't work" - could you be more specific? What actually happens when you put a mailto: link in there?

Comment: I think it would be easiest if you could share a link to the site in question, since, as you mentioned yourself, you don't know what part of the code or which file is generating that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Javascript or Jquery click handler to the  element like this :

```
$("a[href=#contact]").on("click", function() {
    //Your code Here...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for all your suggestions, but I actually just got a response from the designer:

The whole intro navigation is made as a series of same page links using a jQuery 
plugin called jQuery One Page Nav. You can found out more about it here:

https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav

In the `assets/js/custom.curriculum.js` file you can 
locate the script line that enables this navigation:

`$( '#nav ul' ).onePageNav( { scrollSpeed: 400 } );`

Based on the plugin, you can add exceptions via classes. So assuming you want a 
link to keep its default action, you'd add an 'external' class to that link and 
then, replace the code in the JS file with the following one, that adds 
exceptions for 'external' classes:

`$( '#nav ul' ).onePageNav( { scrollSpeed: 400, filter: ':not(.external)' } 
);`